# How can I refresh my live search by hitting on the cross button which is inside the input text field in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am working on a live search. I have made live searching using ajax where whatever alphabet I write in it, it displays the matching result to that alphabet or word. But the issue occurs when I click the cross button inside a search field it will clear the word inside input field but it is not refreshing my search and it is not showing data before a search but the result of the previous search.

I want my live search cross button functionality just like this -https://codepen.io/gastonbesada/pen/eqvJK 
But this is in angular. I want the code in JavaScript.

And this is my code -

//let this page name is index.php

```
<div class="search">
       <i class="fa fa-search" ></i>
      <input type="text" id="searchterm" name="searchterm" placeholder="Search" >   
</div>
<table id="result"></table>
```

//this is the script of index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"search.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }



$('#searchterm').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '')
        {
            load_data(search);
        }
        else
        {
            load_data();            
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

/* Search script for cross button inside input field*/

```
<script>

(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.clearable = function () {
        var $this = this;
        $this.wrap('<div class="clear-holder" />');
        var helper = $('<span title="Press Backspace" class="clear-helper">&times;</span>');
        $this.parent().append(helper);
        $this.parent().on('keyup', function() {
            if($this.val()) {
            helper.css('display', 'inline-block');
            } else helper.hide();
        });
        helper.click(function(){
            $this.val("");
            helper.hide();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$("#searchterm").clearable();
</script>
```

Comment: How do you generate the cross inside the input?

Comment: I updated the cross button script in a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just call your ajax with empty value again what you did in else part.

```
helper.click(function(){
   $this.val("");
   $this.trigger("keyup");
   helper.hide();
});
```